# How to fix "failed to install VS code server" error

Tags: vscode-server

I am trying to connect with remote server using SSH connection from visual studio code. Earlier it was working but now it gives me error:

```
Could not establish connection: Failed to install the VS Code server
```

How can this be fixed?

I was trying to connect the remote server over SSH connection, but somehow, I am not able to connect, and it is giving me error failed to install VS code server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the version which you want by using below command:

```
wget https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/server-linux-x64/stable
```

Once it is downloaded, untar whatever was downloaded.

Move all the files and folder inside the folder which you untar into below path:

```
/home/$user/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
```

You can use below command to move files and folders:

```
mv * /home/$user/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
```

Note: to check commit ID open visual studio code, goto help-> about

Comment: This will cause error. `mv *` will be expanded to `mv a b c d`, which will try to rename `a` to `b`. This may cause an accident deletion of your file.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add in here in my case this exact same issue I found tar wasn't installed so it wasn't properly unpacking the vscode setup.